# What is the significance of using empty get set?

Tags: c#

A `vector3` class is defined like below.

```
public struct Vector3
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Z { get; set; }   
}
```

The code works fine. But what is the significance of using `{ get; set; }` when I can get and set the variables without using it ?

```
public struct Vector3
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;
    public double Z;
}
```

Comment: The process is called encapsulation and have been probably discussed a hundred times.

Comment: those get and sets are not empty like you say in your title. They are filled in automatically to reduce the lines of code in your application. They are replacing what is referred to as "boilerplate" code

Answer (score 1):

It encapsulates the compiler generated field, and provides you, the class or struct developer the ability to update it internally later without breaking your code by simply modifying the get/set part that you care about.

For instance, suddenly never want to return null You can do that by simply changing the empty get. Of course, it means you suddenly need to manually control the variable, but that's a small price to pay for the flexibility.

Don't forget about inheritance: properties are inheritable while fields are not. You can use fields in an inherited class, but not alter their behavior by making them virtual.

Comment: The statement "properties are inheritable while fields are not" is not true. Fields are inheritable - all of the same access modifiers (`public`, `protected`, `internal`, `private`) work with fields and properties.

Comment: Probably meant "overridable"

Comment: That was a typo indeed, thanks for the heads up !

Answer (score 1):

`get` and `set` are accessors, means they're able to access data  in private field. Generally from database.
It is a shortcut to expose data members as public so that you don't need to explicitly create a private data members. C# will creates a private data member for you.

Below example is the detailed form of `get` and `set`.

```
private string X;
public string X
{
    get
    {
        return this.X;
    }
    set
    {
        this.X= value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `Vector3` struct were to implement an interface you would need to specify it like this:

```
public struct Vector3 : IVector
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Z { get; set; }   
}

public interface IVector
{
    double X { get; set; }
    double Y { get; set; }
    double Z { get; set; }  
}
```

You can't create an interface for fields. This is illegal:

```
public interface IVector
{
    double X;
    double Y;
    double Z;
}
```

Now, you can go a little further than this. Let's say you wanted a nice read-only interface on your class, you could do this:

```
public struct ReadOnlyVector3 : IReadOnlyVector
{
    public double X { get; private set; }
    public double Y { get; private set; }
    public double Z { get; private set; }   
}

public interface IReadOnlyVector
{
    double X { get; }
    double Y { get; }
    double Z { get; }
}
```

Now, all of this just boils down to the compiler putting the backing field in for you. It's all just syntactic sugar to make your life easier by writing less code.